# Binding telerik control to a visibility property throws a runtime error

Tags: silverlight-4.0, telerik

I'm having an issue when I try to bind a visibility property to a telerik control.
When I bind the same property to a regular control, it works fine.

I've tried both, Visibility.Collapsed and Telerik.Windows.Controls.Charting.SeriesVisibility.Collapsed, but I still get the following error

> Set property
>   'Telerik.Windows.Controls.Charting.SeriesDefinition.Visibility' threw
>   an exception.

This error is thrown on the Initialize();

Here's my code

View (code behind):

```
public ChartView(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

ViewModel:

```
private Telerik.Windows.Controls.Charting.SeriesVisibility _startDateVisible;
public Telerik.Windows.Controls.Charting.SeriesVisibility StartDateVisible 
{ 
    get {return _startDateVisible;} 
    set 
    {
        _startDateVisible = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("StartDateVisible");
    }
}
public ViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
            : base(eventAggregator)
{
     StartDateVisible = Telerik.Windows.Controls.Charting.SeriesVisibility.Collapsed;
     //StartDateVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

View (XAML):

```
<telerikCharting:SeriesMapping x:Name="..." LegendLabel="..." CollectionIndex="1" ChartAreaName="...">
   <telerikCharting:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
       <telerikCharting:ScatterSeriesDefinition ShowItemLabels="True" ShowItemToolTips="True" PointShape="Circle" Visibility="{Binding StartDateVisible}"  />
       </telerikCharting:SeriesMapping.SeriesDefinition>
   <telerikCharting:SeriesMapping.ItemMappings>
   <telerikCharting:ItemMapping DataPointMember="XValue" FieldName="..."/>
   <telerikCharting:ItemMapping DataPointMember="YValue" FieldName="..."/>
</telerikCharting:SeriesMapping.ItemMappings>
</telerikCharting:SeriesMapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out it's impossible due to dependency issues.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/chart/seriesdefinition-visibility-binding-issue.aspx